# Owl Carousel 2 does not work when using event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, owl-carousel

so i'm trying to learn react ... i have a header with a navbar and if you click on any item of the navbar a function will be executed ... this is the function :

```
clickHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.replace(`/${event.target.textContent}`);
}
```

the function is working but the problem is the owl carousel does not work (does not show app at all) .

**Note : if i reloaded the page it works ... but if i used navigation items it doesn't work.**

please help.

Comment: You should add details on how owl carousel (a jQuery plugin, right?) ties in with your React application; normally jQuery and React aren't mixed.

Comment: @Jacob i have owl carousel necessery css and js files in my src directory and i linked them as i link any css file or js script (in index.html) ... then i called it in a js file containes my custom jquery code by using $('.caro1').owlCarousel({ ... });